# dplyr summarise and group_by for unique values

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a representative example:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = 0, nrow = 9, ncol = 3))
colnames(DF) <- c("code", "actual", "expected")

DF$code <- letters[rep(1:3, each = 3)]
DF$actual <- runif(9, 3,5)
DF$expected <- rep(1:3, each = 3)
```

The following crashes:

```
  DF %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  summarise(Exp = expected)
 Error: expecting a single value
```

However, the following works:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(code) %>%
  summarise(Exp = unique(expected))
```

However, the unique value by code is just one value. Why doesn't returnign the value work? Why do I need to wrap it up in a "unique"?

Thanks!

Comment: mean,median, sd  or what?`summarise(Exp = mean(expected))`?

Comment: I just want it to report the actual value. Not a mean, median or anything. Just that one value. See my example.

Comment: Because you are trying to assign a vector of lets say `c(1,1,1)` to a single value. `group_by` tells `summarise` that it should expect only one value. In some cases even `unique` will fail because of that logic. Try `DF$expected <- 1:9 ; DF %>% group_by(code) %>% summarise(Exp = unique(expected))`. But it's mainly just `dplyr` nonsense. `data.table`, for example, couldn't care less `library(data.table) ; setDT(DF)[, list(Exp = expected), by = code]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Ah, so you're saying "unique" is the way to go. If it's not unique, the code would then crash as the resulting vector would be longer than one?

Comment: How about the `mutate` ?

Comment: `summarise` is expecting a single value, not a vector of values. It turns (say) 10 rows into 1 and only 1. If you wanted, for example, to have a single field indicate all unique values of `expected`, you could coerce it into a pasted string (`Exp=paste(expected,sep=',')`), but I don't know if that's what you're going for. Can you provide the output you are expecting to see?

Comment: @r2evans, I did provide what i wanted.. in my second example that works.

Comment: Maybe it is a silly answer but I read in the ?summarise that it expects a Name-value pairs of functions... maybe without a functions that do something (even if in fact that functions don't to anything), summarize doesn't know what to do.

Comment: No, you provided code that works, not the output that you expect your first code block to produce. For instance, it appears that you want a single cell in the resulting data.frame to contain a *vector* instead of a *scalar*. Though it is possible to have non-scalar entities within cells of a data.frame, it can be problematic and certainly not what I'd call the "norm" in *R* programming. Regardless, `summarise` wants a reply that is of length 1, as evidenced by its description: *"Summarise multiple values to a **single value**"*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a common mistake. One way to debug it is to use paste() in the summarise call.

```
> DF %>% 
     group_by(code) %>% 
     summarise(Exp=paste(expected, collapse='-'))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

   code   Exp
  (chr) (chr)
1     a 1-1-1
2     b 2-2-2
3     c 3-3-3
```

Do you see what is going on? You are trying to assign multiple values to a single group.

One solution is to use unique as you describe. In alternative, if you know that all the rows with the same code have always the same expected value, you can group_by directly:

```
> DF%>% group_by(code, expected) %>% summarise()
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: code [?]

   code expected
  (chr)    (int)
1     a        1
2     b        2
3     c        3
```

If the dataframe is big, group_by will be much faster than the solution based on unique()

Comment: Nice answer. Unique only works inside summarise if you're sure that it is unique / takes only one value, in which case `expected[1]` is another option.